# Generic Data Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to familiarize myself for educational purposes, with a portion of data retrieval.  I've got several different *Data Models* that I'd like to populate.  Rather than use a *Object Relational Mapper* or rebuild singular methods for each form of retrieval I thought about said approach:

```
public List<T> BuildModel<T>(string query) where T : new()
{
     var container = new List<T>();
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
         using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
         {
              connection.Open();
              using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                   while(reader.Read())
                   {
                        T model = new T();

                        // How can I associate said data column, to the property in model?

                        container.Add(model);
                   }
         }

      return container;
}
```

Is my approach feasible, or am I far off?  I feel like I should be able to access said `Anonymous Types` to build the model.  I'm not sure it is possible, but I feel it should be.  As I stated above, this is for educational purposes for myself.

Comment: Looks like you might be interested in Dapper. Written by StackExchange!  https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you'd end up with *is* an ORM (albeit not a very fully functional one), but here's a really basic example:

```
public List<T> BuildModel<T>(string query) where T : new()
{
    var container = new List<T>();

    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var table = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(table);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            T item = new T();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    property.GetSetMethod().Invoke(item, new[] { row[property.Name] });
                }
            }

            container.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return container;
}
```

This uses reflection to attempt to see if each (public) property exists as a column in the result set. Property names must exactly match column names.

Say you had a table `Person`:

```
create table [Person]
(
    [Id] int not null,
    [FirstName] nvarchar(100) not null,
    [LastName] nvarchar(100) not null
);
```

And a corresponding class `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
var people = BuildModel<Person>("select * from Person");
```

Also, concerning anonymous types--I'm not sure they really apply here (did you mean `dynamic`?). You'd need to ditch the type parameter on `BuildModel` and return a `List<object>` if you wanted to return a list of anonymous types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I built it a bit differently but similar.  Your approach filled in some gaps though.

Comment: @Greg: Sure thing, there are definitely a few ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

The approach I built:

```
private List<T> Build<T>(string query) where T : new()
{
    var container = new List<T>();
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    T model = new T();
                    var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

                    var type = model.GetType();
                    foreach(var property in type.GetProperties())
                        foreach(var column in columns)
                            if (String.Compare(property.Name, column, true) == 0)
                                if(!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)))
                                    property.SetValue(model, reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name)), null);

                    container.Add(model);
                }
        }

    return container;
}
```